# Variable inside a while loop does not update the text outside of loop

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a small game. I made a score tracker with font.Font .

```
points = 0
score_text = pygame.font.Font('Pixeltype.ttf',100)
score_surf = score_text.render(f'Current points: {points}', None, 'Green')
```

This is before the while True loop that starts the game. This is pure variable declaration.

Later below, as i defeat 'enemies', I add +100 points to points.

Although my score does not update with `screen.blit(score_surf,(850,40))`, if i call `print(points)`, my points have indeed increased.

I tried creating a separate text element for the points, still had this problem.

I am new to pygame module and i figured out I should practice the stuff i learned before moving on.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Updating `points` doesn't update `score_surf` automatically. There's no link between the rendered element and the variable.

Comment: This string: `f'Current points: {points}'` is evaluated immediately.

Comment: If you change `points` you have to render `score_surf` again.

Comment: How could i go about solving it? I tried to add screen.blit(score_surf, (850,40)) after every enemy elimination condition but i still have 0 points shown.

Comment: As @Rabbid76 said: `score_surf` is still the same. You'll have to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
score_surf = score_text.render(f'Current points: {points}', None, 'Green')
```

Expression `f'Current points: {points}'` gets evaluated only once to variable and passed to the render. It isn't function returning string but only formatted string.

You have to render `score_surf` again after it is changed.

#### How to fix it

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46719847/2976142).